# angular js sending empty data to php using post method

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, xampp

I am making a test application to test angular and php data transfer.
But angular is  sending data through post method but php is not accepting the data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
    <script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
 <form ng-submit="insert()">
   <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="name" placeholder="name">
   <input type="age" ng-model="age" name="age" placeholder="age">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myctrl',function($scope,$http){    


    $scope.insert=function(){    

        $http.post("test.php", {
            'name':$scope.name,
            'age':$scope.age
        }).then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            },function(error){
                alert("Sorry! Data Couldn't be inserted!");
                console.error(error);

            });
        }
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the html code
The php code is

```
<?php


    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $place=$data->name;
    $image=$data->age;
    echo $place;
    echo $image;
    echo "string";
?>
```

When i access these name and age its giving the error as

"
**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php** on line **5**

**Notice**:  Trying to get property of non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php** on line **6**
string"

but angular is sending the data
data:Object 
age:"2"
name:"abcd"
cant identify where is the problem.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but shouldn't it be $name = $_POST['name']; $age = $_POST['age']; ....

Comment: "<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: age in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
string"

Comment: getting this error now. Tried this method also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable cross-origin resource sharing on XAMPP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872760/how-do-i-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

One way to make proper post request to php is through $httpParamSerializerJQLike,

so you can make a post like this:

```
var data = {
        'name':$scope.name,
        'age':$scope.age
    };
var req = {
      method : "POST",
      url: "http://yourUrl",
      data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
      }
    };
 $http(req).then(function(resp){//success}).catch(function(error){//error});
```

Comment: OP is using `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))` which decodes content type `application/json`.

Comment: ReferenceError: $httpParamSerializerJQLike is not defined

Comment: You have to inject it in the controller, next to $http, app.controller('myctrl',function($scope,$http,  $httpParamSerializerJQLike)